# Sunspot sort by multiple date fields

Tags: solr, sunspot, sunspot-rails

I have setup sunspot for my application wherein we have two date field
fields

```
date_of_a
date_of_b
```

and i want to sort records by date field with precedence in given order only i.e `a > b > c ....`

so i setup my search like

```
Sunspot.search(Model) do
  order_by(:date_of_a, :desc)
  order_by(:date_of_b, :desc)
  ..
end
```

now let's say i have 4 documents which have

```
document 1 => date_of_a = 10/2/10
document 2 => date_of_a = 10/2/12
document 3 => date_of_b = 10/2/15
document 4 => date_of_a = 10/2/9
```

and when i try to search it gives me records in following sequence

```
document 2 => date_of_a = 10/2/12
document 1 => date_of_a = 10/2/10
document 3 => date_of_b = 10/2/15  #this document doesn't have `date_of_a`
document 4 => date_of_a = 10/2/9
```

but this is not what i want i want it to sort as per latest date no matter which date it is

so the required result is like

```
document 3 => date_of_b = 10/2/15  #this document doesn't have `date_of_a`
document 2 => date_of_a = 10/2/12
document 1 => date_of_a = 10/2/10
document 4 => date_of_a = 10/2/9
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a method that returns the max of the two dates. Then index on that method:

```
def latest_date
  [date_of_a, date_of_b].max
end

searchable do
  date :latest_date
end
```